# How to monitor USB webcam bandwidth usage?

Tags: 12.04, usb, bandwidth

I would like to find out the amount of bandwidth my USB webcam occupies while I'm using it. I would prefer a command line solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [usbtop](https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop), it gives a nice overview of what devices are using how much bandwidth:

```
Bus ID 1 (USB bus number 1) To device   From device
  Device ID 1 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 2 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
Bus ID 2 (USB bus number 2) To device   From device
  Device ID 1 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 4 :             141.73 kb/s 13777.68 kb/s
  Device ID 5 :             9.98 kb/s   11.24 kb/s
  Device ID 6 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 7 :             0.00 kb/s   0.00 kb/s
  Device ID 8 :             141.71 kb/s 15257.26 kb/s
```

Install and run it like so:

```
$ sudo apt install git cmake g++ libboost-dev libpcap-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-system-dev
$ git clone https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop.git
$ cd usbtop
$ cmake .
$ make
$ sudo src/usbtop
```

Comment: I installed `libboost1.62-all-dev` on my ubuntu server and the cmake step succeeds, but the make step failes with undefined references to `boost::system::system_category()` for example. What else is needed to install?

Comment: @danbru1211 that's strange.. it should pull in `libboost1.62-system-dev`. Which Ubuntu version are you using?
(BTW I've added the dependencies to my answer)

Answer (score 5):

I think this can be done with wireshark.

When it is plug a USB device, in syslog it appear a message like

> Feb  7 21:35:42 Computer kernel: [ 1237.639216] usb 2-1.1.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd

With this information, we know the device was plugged in bus 2 with device number 8.

The fire up wireshark

> $ sudo wireshark

It will appear a list of devices... choose the one with same bus id you plug the device, in this case, "USB bus number 2" and start the capture.

In menu, choose "Statistics" then "IO Graphs".

Then in the graphs options, you can create a filter with just de device you want.

For example:

> (usb.bus_id == 2) && (usb.device_address == 8)

In "X Axis" and "Y Axis" ajust the values to have a graphic with 'normal' values, for example Tick Interval: 1 sec, Unit: Bits/tick, and with that the graphic should be in Bits/sec.

[IO Graphics](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatIOGraphs.html)

Comment: For this to work properly, the usbmon kernel module should be loaded first - http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote a pair of shell scripts to get the throughput from a USB device. If someone what to use it, you can find it in this [post](http://pipe.oliveira-carvalho.com/blog/tech/monitorusbthroughput).

**getUsb.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash  

COUNTER=0;
# first get USB devices
IFS=$'\n'
USBDEVICES=$( lsusb | grep -v "0000:0000" | grep -iv "hub" )
CHOOSED_DEVICE=$(zenity --list  --width=700 --height=500 --title "Connected USB devices" --column="Devices" ${USBDEVICES[@]})
unset IFS

echo ${CHOOSED_DEVICE} 
echo ${CHOOSED_DEVICE} | cut -d: -f 1 | read 

BUS=`echo ${CHOOSED_DEVICE} | cut -d: -f 1 | cut -d\  -f 2`
DEVICE=`echo ${CHOOSED_DEVICE} | cut -d: -f 1 | cut -d\  -f 4`

let BUS=$BUS+0

echo $BUS
echo $DEVICE

# create data to pipe
let totalIN=0;
let totalOUT=0;

echo "usbmon -i ${BUS} | grep "C Bo:${BUS}:${DEVICE}" ";

usbmon -i ${BUS} | grep "C B" | grep "${BUS}:${DEVICE}" | while read  garb1 garb2 garb3 status garb5 value finalGarb; do 
    if [[ $status =~ "Bo" ]]; then
        let totalIN=$totalIN+$value
        echo $totalIN > /tmp/counterUsbIN
    elif [[ $status =~ "Bi" ]]; then
        let totalOUT=$totalOUT+$value
        echo $totalOUT > /tmp/counterUsbOUT
    else
        echo "discarded"
        continue;
    fi
done
```

**speedUsb.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -i

if [ $1 ]; then
    SLEEP=$1;
else
    SLEEP=1;
fi

PREV_VALUE_IN=`cat /tmp/counterUsbIN`
PREV_VALUE_OUT=`cat /tmp/counterUsbOUT`
LINECOUNT=$(tput lines);
while [ 1 ]; do

    if [ $LINECOUNT -ge $(tput lines) ]; then
        printf "%7s %7s \n" "IN" "OUT"
        LINECOUNT=2;
    else
        (( LINECOUNT++ ))
    fi

    sleep $SLEEP
    LAST_VALUE_IN=`cat /tmp/counterUsbIN`
    LAST_VALUE_OUT=`cat /tmp/counterUsbOUT`

    let VALUE_IN=${LAST_VALUE_IN}-${PREV_VALUE_IN}
    let PREV_VALUE_IN=${LAST_VALUE_IN}

    let VALUE_OUT=${LAST_VALUE_OUT}-${PREV_VALUE_OUT}
    let PREV_VALUE_OUT=${LAST_VALUE_OUT}

    mbytesSecIn=`echo "scale = 3; ${VALUE_IN}/${SLEEP}/1024/1024" | bc`
    mbytesSecOut=`echo "scale = 3; ${VALUE_OUT}/${SLEEP}/1024/1024" | bc`

    mbitsSecIn=`echo "scale = 3; ${VALUE_IN}*8/${SLEEP}/1024/1024" | bc`
    mbitsSecOut=`echo "scale = 3; ${VALUE_OUT}*8/${SLEEP}/1024/1024" | bc`

    printf "%7.3f %7.3f Mbytes/s   %7.3f %7.3f Mbits/s\n" ${mbytesSecIn} ${mbytesSecOut} ${mbitsSecIn} ${mbitsSecOut}
done
```

Comment: Hi @Pipe. I tried to follow your blog but could not figure out how to build the `usbmon` userspace program from https://github.com/kkaempf/usbmon . It builds a `usbdump` program, not a `usbmon` program as your scripts are expecting. Can you clarify how you got the dependencies set up?

Comment: Hi Lucas, those scripts where a quick hack and I never try to make it run without root account. It is not very clear in the post, but getUsb.sh must be run as root.